# VMWare Geode (Gemfire) is terribly slow after migrating to 9.15.x

Tags: gemfire, geode, geode9.15.9

I have recently migrated to vmware geode 9.15.9 from Gemfire Pivotal. After this migration, our application became terribly slow. The small queries are taking almost twice of more time than the previous version. Also, when a big data is queried to the geode cache, it fails with socket timeout.
Any clue on what could have gone wrong?

Comment: Perhaps too obvious, but do you have indexes set up (correctly)? If you run your queries with the `<TRACE> SELECT * FROM ...` keyword you'll get some details about execution times and indexes used in the logs.

Comment: @JensD Those indexes aren't touched. Apparently, if I transit back to the Gemfire Pivotal, performance is back to normal. I doubt if there are some configurational tweak that I am missing on both Server and Client side.  But I have no clue which one to tweak.

Comment: I think it would still be useful to run with `<TRACE>` - especially if you can do so on both the 8.x instance and the 9.15 one. That would give us some quantifiable numbers to look at.

Comment: @JensD Thanks. Do you know where the TRACE logs are saved on linux machine? I can't find any such logs.

Comment: I am executing under the gfsh command: gfsh>query --query="<TRACE> SELECT * from /region2"

Comment: The log entries are written to the server logs. Make sure that your `log-level` is at least set to `info`. I would also suggest opening a GemFire support ticket so that you can provide the artifacts - server logs and statistics files would be essential in getting to a root cause.

Comment: log-level is set to info indeed. And I can see the log as well. But can't see the execution time and other trace information. Am I executing the command correctly using gfsh ?